# Javascript join() and concat() one string

Tags: javascript, join, slice, concatenation

I have the problem specified in the picture above.

I'm supposed to take a 3 elements string and join them using ", " and " and " separators.

The issue is join() targets all the elements of the string using one connector only, so I tried to slice() bits of the string and then concat() them together.

However I am stuck since Tuesday since if the string is 3 elements long (any odd number to be honest) I cannot "target" the middle element using slice, as it gets "grabbed" by both join() methods at the same time.

[image: excersize]

Comment: Why do you need to target the middle of the list? What interests you is removing the last element, join with `", "`, then append `"and " and the last element.

Comment: as in the duplicate target, i would get the last to ones first, join it with `' and '` and later join the rest with comma.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can make such "chains" as below:


return array.slice(0, 2).join(", ") + " and " + array[array.length-1];